# In the next major version, Nest will not allow classes annotated with @Injectable(), @Catch(), and @Controller() decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm writing in Nest.js framework for 3 years and i got the message in by backend-application:

```
WARN [DependenciesScanner] In the next major version, Nest will not allow classes annotated with @Injectable(), @Catch(), and @Controller() decorators to appear in the "imports" array of a module.
Please remove "ExternalOrAdmin" (including forwarded occurrences, if any) from all of the "imports" arrays.

Scope [BackendAdminModule -> LicenseModule -> AuthModule]
```

I researched nest.js github and stuck what is the problem and why it says about some deprecation of useable decorators.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or what will be in the next major version of Nest.js framework

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do what it says — "Please remove "ExternalOrAdmin" (including forwarded occurrences, if any) from all of the "imports" arrays."? The decorators are not getting deprecated, but having services in the `imports` is.

Comment: @Joulukuusi, but the main reason that `ExternalOrAdmin` used there as `@UseGuards()`. And maybe it is the point, but without including `AuthModule` i have an error while sending request like `Unknown jwt strategy`.  Most likely it is a lack of my architecture. But i will try to make some workaround. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: `ExternalOrAdmin`, since it's a guard, should then be a part of the `providers` array instead of `imports` — please ensure that this is true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

only modules should be listed in the `imports` array. That's why this **wrong** usage won't be allowed in v9 anymore.

Read the docs on modules: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules